# Byte array initialisation syntax - specify first 20 bits and pad rest with 0s

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization, hex, byte

My goal is to get a 64bit value hence a byte array of size 8. However my problem is that I want to set the first 20 bits myself and then have the rest to be 0s. Can this be done with the shorthand byte array initialisation?

E.g. if I wanted all 0s I would say:

```
byte[] test = new byte[] {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

**What I've thought about/tried:**

So each hexadecimal digit corresponds to 4 binary digits. Hence, if I want to specify the first 20bits, then I specify the first 5 hexadecimal digits? But I'm not sure of how to do this:

```
byte[] test = new byte[] {0xAF, 0x17, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

That would mean that I've specified the first 24 bits right? And not 20.

I could use a `BitArray` and do it that way but I'm just wondering whether it can be done in the above way.

Comment: There is no padding, there is *masking*. If you apply *OR mask*, then you keep only needed bits, rest are `0`.

Comment: You´re right: you should specify *5* hexadecimal digits. All the other should be zeros. The last significant term (`0x10` in your case) should be in `0x?0` format where `?` is a hex digit

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
byte byte1 = 0xFF;
byte byte2 = 0xFF;
byte byte3 = 0xFF;

//                         8bits    8bits        4bits : total = 20 bits
//                       11111111 11111111      11110000
byte[] test = new byte[] { byte1, byte2, (byte)(byte3 & 0xF0), 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you did there. But is there any difference between your example and e.g. `byte[] test = new byte[] {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 }; ` ?

Comment: He is bitwise anding  (the & 0xF0) look it up.

Comment: @D.Singh No difference in this example, but using `&` is useful in case `byte3` is not 0xFF but some value that is not a constant, and you only are interested in the first 4 bits of it

Comment: @Blaatz0r I know what he's doing, I was asking whether there was any difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your bytes backward, and use [`BitConverter.GetBytes(long)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93ae9768(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(0x117AF);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/9VXXQf)

Since each hex digit corresponds to a single four-bit *nibble*, you can initialize data in "increments" of four bits. However, the data written in reverse will be almost certainly less clear to human readers of your code.